# SQL SUM confusion

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, sum

I have run the below query for my data:-

```
SELECT     CONTRACTNAME,
           AccountNo,
           TransDate, 
           JournalNo,
           AuditTrail,           
           Description,       
           CONTRACTNUMBER,
           GROUPING(CONTRACTNUMBER) as CONTRACTNUMBER,   
           SUM(PAFeebillamount)as Total  
FROM       SRVS.dbo.BTQGLDistributionsWithProjectCodesHM
WHERE      TransDate > '2012' AND CONTRACTNUMBER <> '00900'
GROUP BY   CONTRACTNAME,  
           AccountNo,   
           TransDate,
           JournalNo, 
           AuditTrail,    
           Description,      
           CONTRACTNUMBER with rollup  
ORDER BY   GROUPING (CONTRACTNUMBER)
```

this gives me the results:-

[image]

how can I change this so I get a single line Total for each contract number.  So it looks like the below example:-

[image]

at this moment in time I am not bothered about the accnt no / journal no etc as it is only going to be a summary.

Just looking for advice on best way to sum up my groups by contract number?

Comment: But what to return in `accntNo`, `journalNo` etc If you aren't bothered?

Comment: That's another issue.  happy with NULL values or zeros at the moment.  I will probably even take them out from being displayed.  Just looking at the best way to try and get the Total Sum first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT     CONTRACTNAME,
           '' AccountNo,
           '' TransDate, 
           '' JournalNo,
           '' AuditTrail,           
           '' Description,       
           CONTRACTNUMBER,
           GROUPING(CONTRACTNUMBER) as CONTRACTNUMBER,   
           SUM(PAFeebillamount)as Total  
FROM       SRVS.dbo.BTQGLDistributionsWithProjectCodesHM
WHERE      TransDate > '2012' AND CONTRACTNUMBER <> '00900'
GROUP BY   CONTRACTNAME,                  
           CONTRACTNUMBER with rollup  
ORDER BY   GROUPING (CONTRACTNUMBER)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT CONTRACTNAME, CONTRACTNUMBER, grouping(CONTRACTNUMBER) as CONTRACTNUMBER
SUM(PAFeebillamount)as Total
FROM SRVS.dbo.BTQGLDistributionsWithProjectCodesHM 
WHERE TransDate > '2012' AND CONTRACTNUMBER <> '00900' 
GROUP BY 
  CONTRACTNAME,
  CONTRACTNUMBER with rollup
ORDER BY GROUPING (CONTRACTNUMBER)
```

This should give you a total for each contract you have.  The reason you get multiple results is because you are grouping on the contractName, Acct, Date, JournalNo, AuditTrail, and Desc.  If you want a complete total(one for each contract number) then you need to be grouping just on the contract number.

Answer (score 0):

Since you arn't bothered about what to select for `AccountNo, TransDate, etc`, you can use `MAX` as an aggregate function something like:

```
SELECT
  CONTRACTNAME, 
  MAX(AccountNo), 
  MAX(TransDate), 
  MAX(JournalNo),
  MAX(AuditTrail),
  MAX(Description),
  CONTRACTNUMBER, 
  GROUPING(CONTRACTNUMBER) as CONTRACTNUMBER, 
  SUM(PAFeebillamount)as Total
FROM SRVS.dbo.BTQGLDistributionsWithProjectCodesHM 
WHERE TransDate > '2012' 
  AND CONTRACTNUMBER <> '00900' 
GROUP BY 
  CONTRACTNAME,
  CONTRACTNUMBER with rollup
ORDER BY GROUPING (CONTRACTNUMBER)
```

And If you don't want them just remove them from the `SELECT` statement, or replace them with `NULL` or `''`:

```
SELECT
  CONTRACTNAME,
  CONTRACTNUMBER, 
  GROUPING(CONTRACTNUMBER) as CONTRACTNUMBER, 
  SUM(PAFeebillamount)as Total
FROM SRVS.dbo.BTQGLDistributionsWithProjectCodesHM 
WHERE TransDate > '2012' 
  AND CONTRACTNUMBER <> '00900' 
GROUP BY 
  CONTRACTNAME,
  CONTRACTNUMBER with rollup
ORDER BY GROUPING (CONTRACTNUMBER)
```